# My m2eclipse seems to be missing the automatic dependency resolution in Eclipse "fix it" menu

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I've been trying to get more out of m2eclipse, learning what's possible, etc. Recently I watched t[his tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H8QdjyCB8Nw) on how the Eclipse auto-fix will automatically search maven repositories for dependencies. In the video, the presenter begins typing in Java code:

```
RestClient restClient = ...
```

They can right click on the unrecognized "RestClient" and have m2eclipse search for possible dependencies. I don't appear to have this option. Instead I get the standard fixes -- Create a class, interface, etc or fix the project setup.

I created my project by doing "Import Existing Maven Project" in Eclipse. It appears to otherwise work as an existing/normal maven project

(I am using Eclipse Juno with m2eclipse 1.4.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This option was removed from m2e a few years back (right before m2e 1.0 IIRC, when the project was contributed to the Eclipse Foundation), because it required downloading a very large nexus index (known as full index, containing class lists for each known dependencies) of remote repositories. This was slow and very space consuming, the gain was not deemed significant enough to justify maintaining the feature.